# Alignment of `\vdots` in a column of array environment for a system of linear equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

A system of linear equations is displayed in an `array` environment in the following code. I have one ellipsis to typeset vertically. How do I get the them centered in the same column as the equals signs?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}r@{{}}l}
a_{1,1}x_{1} + a_{1,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{1,n}x_{n} &   {}={}   b_{1} \\
a_{2,1}x_{1} + a_{2,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{2,n}x_{n} &   {}={}   b_{2} \\
\vdots \\
a_{m,1}x_{1} + a_{m,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{m,n}x_{n} &   {}={}   b_{m}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: somewhat off topic ... `\cdots` would be preferred over `\ldots` between plus signs.  see the (new!) [ams style guide](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-print.pdf), (print) page 103.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(I'm not sure if I understand you correctly)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rcl}
a_{1,1}x_{1} + a_{1,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{1,n}x_{n} & = & b_{1} \\
a_{2,1}x_{1} + a_{2,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{2,n}x_{n} & = & b_{2} \\
                                                    & \vdots &  \\
a_{m,1}x_{1} + a_{m,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{m,n}x_{n} & = & b_{m}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep.  That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Why do you have `1pt` for the `\arraycolsep` command?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, with `\arraycolsep` I reduce space around `=`. default value is 6pt (if I recall correctly).

Comment: I will reduce it to `0pt` and use `{}={}`.  So, the spacing about the equal signs in each equation in the system of linear equations will be consistent with the spacing about equal signs in other `equation` environments in my file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible use `align*` environment of the `amsmath` package (required by `mathtools` package and by `amsart` class). `mathtools` provides the `\vdotswithin{<symbol>}` and `\shortvdotswithin{<symbol>}` commands precisely to center `\vdots` between *symbols* (`\MTFlushSpaceAbove` and `\MTFlushSpaceBelow` commands manage space around) as is explained in [mathtools *documentation*](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) (page 22 *of version 2015-11-12*).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Using \textsf{align*} environment

\begin{align*}
a_{1,1}x_{1} + a_{1,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{1,n}x_{n} &= b_{1} \\
a_{2,1}x_{1} + a_{2,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{2,n}x_{n} &= b_{2} \\
\shortvdotswithin{=}
a_{m,1}x_{1} + a_{m,2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{m,n}x_{n} &= b_{m}
\end{align*}

or \textsf{alignat*} with 3 alignment blocks to align also by the $+$ sign.

\begin{alignat*}{3}
a_{1,1}x_{1} &+ {} & a_{1,2}x_{2} &+ \ldots + {} & a_{1,n}x_{n} &= b_{1} \\
a_{2,1}x_{1} &+ {} & a_{2,2}x_{2} &+ \ldots + {} & a_{2,n}x_{n} &= b_{2} \\
\MTFlushSpaceAbove
&\vdotswithin{+}   &              &              &              &\vdotswithin{=}
\MTFlushSpaceBelow       
a_{m,1}x_{1} &+ {} & a_{m,2}x_{2} &+ \ldots + {} & a_{m,n}x_{n} &= b_{m}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]